# UI button not coming in success message

Tags: neo4j

I am new to `Neo4j` and was taking the help of a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_cql_create_node.htm) I found online at tutorialspoint.

On the page, an image shows the UI view button along with the success message, but I when I create a node, I do not see the button.

Success message that comes after I create a node-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "Execute" button is displayed in your image (near the top right, looking like a right-pointing triangle in a circle). It can be used to execute any Cypher code in the box to its left.